# Select Pattern with dependencie of 2 lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

How to select / filter content from logfile with dependencie of 2 lines.
I need to filter out content  from logfile, if “pattern1” in current line is followed by “pattern2” in the next line?

Example: line 1 to 7

```
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    CHECK SRBR 820224  APPUSER       12   
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE APPUSER 866
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR SITUATION A                  
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    CHECK SRBR 820224 
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    CHECK SRBR 820224 
18.07.19 23.44.01  APP1    ROLLBACK
```

If occurred

```
DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE
```

in the current line           followed   by the content

```
OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR SITUATION
```

in the next line
then I want to filter out this both line´s.

An single event of `DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE` or `OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR SITUATION` i need to know.

If I use

```
sed -n '/DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE/,/OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR/!p'
```

Line 5 from the example is also filtered out

Which syntax / tool can support this I prefer grep, sed or awk. 
Thanks a lot, Steff

Answer (score 0):

This would print the two lines

```
awk '/OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR SITUATION/ && p~/DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE APPUSER/ {print $0"\n"p} {p=$0}'
18.07.19 23.44.01 APP1 OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR SITUATION A
18.07.19 23.44.01 APP1 DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE APPUSER 866
```

It tested if line is `OPTI-LOCK....` and the previous line is `DATABASE...` and print both.

Comment: thanks, the pattern matching works fine. but i need the output from the logfile without this two lines in the case of occouring only this lines are followed line by line in the logfile.for the example means, I need the output from line 1 and 4-7 to print out. steff

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE/{N;/OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR/d;P;D}' file
```

If the current line contains `DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE` append the next and if this contains `OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR` delete both, otherwise print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: thanks, unfortunatly is there no "gnu sed" avalible on the system

Comment: @Steff give it a try as is, it may well work perfectly.

Comment: sed '/DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE/{N;/OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR/d;P;D}' /tmp/opti_sr_4_stackoverflow                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------sed: command garbled: /DATABASE ERROR ------> PROGRAM FAILURE/{N;/OPTI-LOCK-FORCE-ERROR/d;P;D}

Comment: Hi Potong, I tested on newer Rhel System, your command works fine, but on  Solaris 10 not.